# CSS/Jquery Layout: make two columns same height

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

To be honest, I am not strong on CSS layout. My question is to make the left sidebar having the same height with the right context part.
My web code structure:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTest.Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<link href="Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <asp:Button ID="Lookup" runat="server" Text="Lookup" CssClass="nav_buttons" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="sidebar_buttons"
            OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" CssClass="sidebar_buttons" />
    </div>

        <div id="gridview">

        </div>
        <div id="btnSave">
            <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server"   Text="Edit" OnClientClick="javascript:Edit_Click();return false;"  CssClass="btnEdit"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btnEdit" OnClientClick="javascript:Cancel_Click();return false;" />
        </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var divwrap = $("#wrap").height();
            var divgridview = $("#gridview").height();
            var divheader = $("#header").height();
            var divnav = $("#nav").height();
            var divbtn = $("#btnSave").height();
            $("#sidebar").height(divbtn);

        });

        $('.sidebar_buttons').click(function (event) {
            $("#<%=Edit.ClientID %>").show();
            $("#<%=Cancel.ClientID %>").show();
        }); 
    </script>
</div>
```

The web page snapshot:
[image: Test page]
The sidebar is a little higher then the right. Not sure which variable should be used in jquery. When I debugged into the code, I found divbtn is a big number, why?
CSS:

```
#wrap
{
width: 800px;
background-color: #99c;
}
#header
{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #ddd;
width: 800px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#nav
{
background-color: #c99;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
width: 800px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}
#sidebar
{
float: left;
width: 125px;
padding-top: 10px;
background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#gridview
{
float: right;
overflow: scroll;
width: 675px;
}



.sidebar_buttons
{
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 2px;
 width: 120px;
}

h1
{
margin-left: 50px;
}
.nav_buttons
{
 margin-left: 50px;
 width: 120px;
}


.btnEdit
{
 width: 60px;
 margin-left: 75px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 }

#btnSave
{
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: try to use firefox firebug , or its extension in other browser, than inspect the are which is giving problem to you. you can also dynamically change the design and see the effect very quickly.

Comment: There is a scroll. Does it affect the height?

Answer (score 0):

They are the same height. The only difference is the, sidebar has narrow border on top and content section has thicker border on top.

I would try this solution. Make the border thicker on sidebar side (the part which has button 1 and button 2) or make the top border narrower on the right side.

```
// this is one solution
#sidebar{
    border-top-width:2px; <-- set 2px to what ever is right
}

// this is another
#gridview{
    border-top-width:2px; <-- set 2px to what ever is right
}
```

Comment: What did you mean left? Sidebar? Could you please rewrite your entire code?

Comment: I updated my answer. Not this is an approximate solution as I do not have live code with me.

Answer (score -1):

I use would a horizontal list, instead of the 2 divs as columns, but that's just me.

Comment: It is if you want to have the same height for both columns without using javascript. What your doing cannot be done without javascript or using fixed heights, hence the lack of answers. Try putting your script inside a <div> and below the script tag itself, put <div style=clear: right; background: #SCRIPTCOLOR;"></div>. I'm not sure that will work though. You should use a list.